# Ubuntu OS on Laptop has been hacked & remotely monitored

Tags: ssh, hacking

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, accidentally discovered some screenshots that I didn't take in "Pictures" folder. The screenshots are taken **within a limited time period of 1 minute**. I'm attaching a screenshot of what it looks like:   [My Picture Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oMqY.png)

I've been victim of this previously in January 2020 while using the same system, but that was screencast/screen-record. *I tried to check logs, but logs are cleared before November 1st (Today is November 5, my system was hacked in 27th October)*. I want to find out about the hacker and how he got access to my system.

**Edit:** More Screenshots attached : [1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fguf.png), [/var/log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwIir.png)

***Latest Edit: The logs between the time period the screenshots were taken:*** [Logs of the time of taking screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYTCG.png)

Comment: Are these screenshots the only evidence of the "hacking"? Is it impossible that a keyboard shortcut was accidentally keyed? Aside from someone having physical access to your system, it's unlikely that you were hacked remotely, unless you have been actively putting your system in harm's way (ex. running commands you saw on some blog without understanding the consequences of what they do, installing sketchy software, etc)

Comment: How do you know that you didn't take those screenshots accidentally? i.e. a paperweight fell on the printscr key? Have the logs been cleared, or only rotated?

Comment: Additionally, the logs' evidence just doesn't add up. Why would the attacker have the presence of mind to delete logs but not the screenshots? Why wouldn't they clear the logs immediately after the attack instead of 4 days later?

Comment: @Nmath , Yes I have proof. In one of the screenshots, I was seen adjusting the brightness of the screen, and I didn't use shortcuts and I'm sure of it, as I've mentioned, I've been attacked like that before, that was screencasting, means I got videos instead of photos back then.

Comment: @NonnyMoose I've mentioned it in my post, my logs have been cleared. There is no log before November 1st and these photos were taken in 27th of October.

Comment: @NonnyMoose they've cleared it regularly, because they've access to the system. To Everyone, I've attached more screenshots in the main post.

Comment: Check to make sure the logs have not been rotated. If the logs have been rotated, there will be one or more auth.log.#, possibly with a .gz extension, containing the rest of the logs.

Comment: @NonnyMoose, I've added the screenshot of the logfile you were looking for. I'm not a Linux expert, but it looks like there is no mention of taking screenshot between the time period.

Comment: " I'm not a Linux expert" but you do feel confident to claim you got hacked? why? do you have a good password for your admin account? Because... they only way for someone to remotely hack into your machine you need to be running a server on your machine or they need to know of an exploit to abuse that the rest of the world does not know about. With a normal desktop and a decent password no-one gets into your machine unless you also provide tools to let them that are not installed on a desktop by default. and that is just the start why I doubt you are hacked. None of the links suggest a hack :)

Comment: It really sound to be a mistake, simply pressing the print screen key takes this kind of screenshot. Why an hacker will keep those file without hiding them, it doesn't make sense. It is really feasible to run command remotely, but most hacker run hidden process. Anyway, if you have a doubt, the only way to fix that is reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: @SevenSea Suppose you are correct... What do you expect anyone here to do about it? You also haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @SevenSea I see no evidence here that your system has been compromised. As you can see, your logs have not been deleted, only rotated, which is a [normal process](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/logrotate.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that you system has been compromised:

1. Take your system off the network.
2. Reinstall Ubuntu.
3. Restore your data from safe backups. If you didn't make regular backups, then you may have learned a painful lesson. Backups are a good idea for lots of reasons, and very easy to set up.
4. Upon starting with your restored system, change any online passwords that were stored on the compromised system. An encrypted password manager is another way to prevent a lot of pain.

- A compromised system cannot be "repaired" or "locked down". It is unwise to preserve any data from the compromised system, as you may merely compromise the new system.